# MongoDB Atlas throws error with $in operator

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, changestream

I have developed an app with local version of community MongoDB (v4.4). Now I've connected to Mongo Atlas  (it's running v 4.2).

I'm running a watch command to create a changestream.
While with my local setup everything works, with atlas I get an error

```
MongoError: Error validating $match value for change streams. err=ns field has bson.D value that is not string or valid MongoDb RegEx: Error parsing value [{$in [somestring1 somestring2 somestring3]}] to RegEx: Must specify $regex field
```

The query, resp. watch pipeline is

```
Database.watch([
    {
        "$match":{
                "ns.coll":{
                    "$in":["somestring1","somestring2","somestring3"]
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    {fullDocument:"updateLookup"}
)
```

I've changed it to `$or` alternative:

```
Database.watch([
        {
            "$match":{
                "$or":[
                    {"ns.coll":"somestring1"},
                    {"ns.coll":"somestring2"},
                    {"ns.coll":"somestring3"}
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    {fullDocument:"updateLookup"}
)
```

This works correctly.
The `Database` is a connection from nodejs driver. And the error is an immediate response from atlas server after calling the watch.

The error has also this properties:

```
  ok: 0,
  code: 8000,
  codeName: 'AtlasError'
```

What's the problem? What can/should I do about it?
While the workaround works, I guess it is less performant.

Comment: Add complete queries to the question.

Comment: @D.SM Added It, can You help?